# Unique rows in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I have a query which returns a set of records as like the one below:-

```
Date    Dept        commission

5-Apr   Sales       20
4-Apr   Sales       21
1-Jan   Marketing   35
```

---

case 1: If i run a query between 1 Jan and 5 april I should get

```
Date    Dept        commission

5 April Sales       76
```

---

case 2: and when I run the query between jan 1 and jan 31  should get the output as

```
Date    Dept        commission

1 Jan   Marketing   35
```

---

Case 2 is simple as when i put hte date range getting the required results , but not sure how to handle case 1 to show the max / latest date , the Dept for that date and a sum of the commission for that Dept , date for the selected date range . The output will be a single row with the latest date and department with a sum(commission) for the selected date range.

Comment: :If you run the query for first case ,you should get 4april and 5th April ,and for case 2 ,you should get 4th and 5th April ,but you're result is coming different?

Comment: Hi Sorry that was a typo from my end it should be 1 Jan to 31 jan

Comment: And where did that `71` come from? @priya: You can edit your question.

Comment: hi 71 is the sum of 20+21+35 = 76 oops ...one more typo

Comment: @priyaravi:can you please correct you're question.

Comment: @priyaravi: OK, 76=20+21+35 but then the output is not correct. Those 76 are not all related to Sales. The 35 are related to Marketing.

Comment: @ypercube: yes 35 is for marketing and 41 is for sales , the user req is like this that for the given date range the date and dept should always reflect the current ones and the sum of commission should be for the entire date range!

Comment: I thought of like to use a subquery to  get a max of date from the given date range and trying to display the Dept name from that, but not sure how to write that query:)

Comment: @priyaravi:one question for case 1 you need to display `5april sales 41` right? and date will be max means between 4th april and 5th april ? right ?

Comment: @GauravSoni: No Gaurav for a given date range i should display the latest Dept for the latest date selected ( in this case april5) and the total of commission for the selected time period.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    MAX(Date)                     AS Date
  , ( SELECT tt.Dept                            
      FROM tableX tt 
      WHERE tt.Date = MAX(t.Date) 
    )                             AS Dept
  , SUM(Commission)               AS Commission
FROM
    tableX t
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

The above works in SQL-Server, MySQL, Postgres as the [sql-fiddle, test-1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c2e5/16) shows, however it does NOT work in Oracle 11g R2 !

---

This works though ([sql-fiddle, test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c2e5/19)):

```
SELECT
    MAX(t.Date)        AS Date
  , MIN(tt.Dept)       AS Dept               --- MIN, MAX irrelevant
  , SUM(t.Commission)  AS Commission
FROM
  ( SELECT
       MAX(Date)                      AS Date
     , SUM(Commission)                AS Commission
    FROM
       tableX 
    WHERE
       Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
  ) t
  JOIN
    tableX tt
      ON tt.Date = t.Date
```

The `MIN(tt.Dept)` is used to take care of the case you have more than row with the maximum date, say one row with `Sales` and one with `Marketing`, both in `Apr-5`

This works, too, using the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function ([sql-fiddle, test-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=4/7c2e5/19#!4/7c2e5/33)):

```
SELECT
    MAX(Date)        AS Date
  , MIN(Dept)        AS Dept               
  , SUM(Commission)  AS Commission
FROM
  ( SELECT
       Date                      AS Date
     , LAST_VALUE(Dept) OVER( ORDER BY Date
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING 
                            )    AS Dept
     , Commission                AS Commission
    FROM
       tableX 
    WHERE
       Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
  ) t
```

Comment: will try your query and reply.